# Does LightTable's vim mode support regex substitution?

Tags: vim, editor, lighttable

In LightTable, I've installed the `vim` plugin and activated it in `user.behaviors`. I can perform basic navigation and text editing with vim bindings, but when I try to do a command like:

```
:%s/test/prod/g
```

... this doens't work. Instead, typing ":" opens a right-hand bar sidebar like:
[image]

But typing a "substitute" command into this box has no effect (can't press enter on completion):[image]

I've confirmed that the "substitute" *is supported* by [CodeMirror's vim mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html) on which LightTable's vim mode is based.

Would appreciate any advice on how to do this properly!

Comment: I just skimmed through the source code. Yes substitute is inside the javascript. No it does not appear to be exposed to the user. I would recommend asking on the issue tracker for the vim plugin you are using. (You can get there by clicking on source inside the plugin manager)

Answer (score -1):

If your using something like `vim`, I believe you need to declare `sed` before making a regex expression like `s/test/prod/g`. Try typing this in your script:

`sed 's/test/prod/g'`

EDIT: When I was researching LightTable, i found the syntax to be slightly different:

`sed([options ,] search_regex, replace_str, file)`

For example:

`sed('-i', 'PROGRAM_VERSION', 'v0.1.3', 'source.js');`

- `-i`: Replace contents of 'file' in-place. Note that no backups will be created!